# Nancarrow piano studies collections: why are they ordered that way?

Tags: history

The bulk of Conlon Nancarrow's musical output has been collected in the series [Conlon Nancarrow: Studies for Player Piano (vol.s 1-5)](https://en.schott-music.com/shop/studies-for-player-piano-album-plus-booklet-noq51789.html). My question is about the ordering of songs in this collection. For example, according to [this chronology](http://www.nancarrow.de/chronology.htm) study #7 was completed by 1962 and study #44 was completed in 1981, but they appear in volumes III and I of the collection respectively.

So the whole thing seems pretty ahistorical. Given that, what organizing principle *was* at work here?

One reason I ask is that the given ordering actually works quite nicely (to me anyways) - I find the pieces quite pleasant to listen to in the given order, even when the chronological jumps are rather extreme as far as I can tell. So while it seems quite strange to me, I can imagine it being a purely aesthetic choice.

(I only have a digital copy of a couple volumes; it's quite possible the physical CD version explains the criteria in the liner notes, but I don't have those.)

---

There seem to be very few relevant tags existing, and I don't have the reputation to create more. In particular, I think this question should additionally be tagged "nancarrow" (or similar) and "collections" (or similar). Please feel free to add additional tags as appropriate.

Comment: Incidentally, for those interested in Nancarrow's music I recommend the following as an introduction: first [this version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R-AWEYJVKyo) of study 7, and then [this version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6bct4T9Ikl4) of study 12. It should be noted that the former is *not* according to Nancarrow's intent - it's transposed down a bit and is on a smoother-sounding player piano - but I think it's still a good way to ease into the strangeness (and actually I prefer it, blasphemous though that may be).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[an attempt to reply to your question, though I feel a whole doctoral disertation could easily be dedicated to this subject alone!]
You have 2 questions about the Nancarrow Piano Studies which are intrinsically linked: their **chronology** and **ordering in cd**.

The most discussion I found about the chronology are from:
[Dated and annotated list of the works, premieres and arrangements of the music of Conlon Nancarrow](http://fuerst-heidtmann.de/html/nancarrow_works.html) [well worth a read]

The main points I gathered from this were:

- a number of people put together different chronological lists over time and came to different conclusions.
- there are **three** types of *score* for **most** of the studies:

  1. a pre-punching score as a guide
  2. a piano roll
  3. a standard music notation score
- between about 1960–1965 he worked mainly *catching-up* writing music notation scores for the already made piano rolls.
- (Gerhard) Trimpin* during 1988–1992 converted all the piano rolls to the midi file format.
- There's an impressive chronology list of **all** works known at the end at the above web page.

* simply known as **Trimpin**.

From the same site, different page:
[Interviews with Conlon Nancarrow (1980-1993) by Monika Fürst-Heidtmann [Various interviews on June 1987, Jan. 1980, May 1984, Nov. 1993 and Oct. 1991 and letters between 1980 and 1993]](http://fuerst-heidtmann.de/html/nancarrow-interviews.htm)

> I don’t remember any dates, but the sequence of the numbered pieces (Studies for Player Piano) is more or less regular, except that occasionally I would go on to a new number before finishing a previous one, and later return to it. Also there was a period of about five years when I didn’t do any pieces (1960-1965?).

It further explains:

- earlier pieces done on a machine that could  only punch relations of sixteenth notes.
- After study 21 has new machine that can move to any point in the roll (not limited to the sixteenth notes).
- Earlier pieces in standard notation, no drawing on the roll.
- Renumbered 38 & 39 to 43 & 48.
- 45 split into five pieces

  - renumbered three of the five
  - rewrote one of the five
  - withdrew [implied] one of the five

---

#### Recordings of Nancarrow's Complete Studies

This seems to be the first complete set of the studies and this is were the original ordering of the 50-odd studies seems to come from.
[*Cn* = Catalogue Number; *rd* = release date; *ts* = tracks]

> **1750 Arch Records Volumes** recorded 1977
>
> - *Vol. 1*, *cn*: 1768, *rd*: 1977,  *ts*: no. 3a–e, 20, 41a–c.
> - *Vol. 2*, *cn*: 1777, *rd*: 1979, *ts*: no. 5, 6, 14, 22, 26, 31, 35, 4, 32, 37, 40a–b.
> - *Vol. 3*, *cn*: 1786, *rd*: 1981, *ts*: Sonatina. no. 1, 2, 7, 8, 10, 15, 21, 23–25, 33.
> - *Vol. 4*, *cn*: 1798, *rd*: 1984, *ts*: no. 9, 11–13, 16–19, 27–29, 34, 36.

> **Wergo** Studies For Player Piano (various volumes), recorded 1988
> [various recordings, *rd*: 1990 seems earliest]
>
> - *Vol. 1*, *ts*: no. 3a–e, 20, 44, 41a–c.
> - *Vol. 2*, *ts*: no. 4, 5, 6, 14, 22, 26, 31, 35, 32, 37, Tango?, 40a–b.
> - *Vol. 3* *ts*: no. 1 2a, 2b, 7, 8, 10, 15, 21, 23, 24, 25, 33, 43, 50.
> - *Vol. 4* *ts*: no. 9, 11, 12, 13, 16, 17, 18, 19, 27, 28, 29, 34, 36, 46, 47.
> - *Vol.5* *rd*: 1991 seems earliest, *ts*: no. 42, 45a–c, 48a–c, 49a–c.

> **Other Minds** *cn*: OM1012/15-2, *rd*:  2008
> (re-release but remastered of 1750 Arch Records recorded 1977)

In [Other Minds liner notes [archive.org site, pdf file]](https://archive.org/download/cd_studies-for-player-piano_conlon-nancarrow_2/cd_studies-for-player-piano_conlon-nancarrow_2.pdf)
[from original 1750 Arch Records, Volume 1, James Tenney, 1977, p15]:

> "Nancarrow is unusually reticent about the history of his work, both in terms of biographical information ("it's nobody's business") and with respect to any precise chronology of the *Studies* themselves (the scores are not dated, and he says "it doesn't matter much").... Nancarrow ...[numbered] ... the *Studies* although ... [the numbers do] ... not always correspond exactly to the chronological order in which the pieces were composed. ... [E]arlier pieces ... have been withdrawn from the set ... Nos. 40 and 41 ... may have been completed before earlier-numbered pieces were finished (... Nos. 38 and 39). ... I think it's safe to assume that the numbering of the *Studies* may be taken as at least an approximate indication of their chronological order ...."

So the *complete* ordering comes from the 1750 Arch Records recordings. I'd speculate the numbers for each were given in 1977, 1979, 1981 and 1984.

The [Wergo liner notes [archive.org site, pdf file]](https://archive.org/download/cd_studies-for-player-piano_conlon-nancarrow_3/cd_studies-for-player-piano_conlon-nancarrow_3.pdf) are totally amazingly analytical, but I don't see much more than already said.

---

[Kyle Gann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kyle_Gann) (an authority on Nancarrow since at least 1995 when he published  *The Music of Conlon Nancarrow*) suggests that, among many things,  Nancarrow:

- Called studies a higher number than what they were to give the impression he composed more than he did to get comissions
- basically has year of composition and number of study all over the place, not corresponding to each other at all
- > *from* [Outside the Feedback Loop: A Nancarrow Keynote Address](https://mtosmt.org/issues/mto.14.20.1/mto.14.20.1.gann.html)
  >
  > > I’ve looked it up, and no calculator available in the 1970s was capable of cube roots. How did he do it? He didn’t remember.

  [A "Nancarrow" search on Kyle Gann's Postclassical blog](https://www.artsjournal.com/postclassic/?s=nancarrow)

---

I do wonder if the 1750 Arch Records 1977 recording was all recorded at the same time, in 1977, since 1977 to 1984—**seven years**—is a long time to released a product that is very near to completion.

There is also the idea that later pieces had a flavour of earlier pieces with a Spanish influence and Jazz. Could these later pieces have not been later reworkings of old pieces already written?

Answer (score 4):

I agree that the liner notes would be a good starting place. A music school library would be a good place to look. (The music school library near me is temporarily, but indefinitely, closed. If and when possible, I'll update my answer with what I find there. The CDs, and presumably the booklet, are in their collection.)

Another place to look would be reviews of the collection. Here are the ones I've found:

- Scholz, Carter. 1992. "[Book Review: Conlan Nancarrow: Studies for Player Piano, Vols. 1-5](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1575739?seq=1)". Leonardo. 25 (2): 231-232.
- Fürst-Heidtmann, Monika. 1991. "[Book Review: Studies für Player Piano, Vol. III & IV](https://www.jstor.org/stable/23985387?seq=1)". Neue Zeitschrift Für Musik (1991-). 152 (5): 51-52.

As far as overall considerations, aesthetics could certainly be one. Since it's a CD release, the overall timing would be an issue, making sure the music fits efficiently on a given disc. Other considerations could be musical or compositional relationships between studies, such as instrumentation or compositional focus.

Finally, I stumbled onto [Studies for Player Piano by Conlon Nancarrow](https://othermindsrecords.bandcamp.com/album/studies-for-player-piano), which might interest you. The site indicates that "the studies are presented in their original order, selected by the composer."